Can anyone help me simplify the complex nested aggregation in an Elasticsearch? Or is it final result
I am trying to understand how to dynamically build the aggregations with nested and regular filters for regular or nested fields, so, my final query looks like code below and would be fine if it can be simplified to two levels (first - level of filters, second - level of a terms query)
{
  "aggs": {
    "city": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "locations"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "city": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "locations.country.id": [
                      "4"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "city": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "city": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "category.id": [
                              "24"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "city": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "locations"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "city": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "locations.city.id",
                            "size": 1000
                          },
                          "aggs": {
                            "source": {
                              "top_hits": {
                                "size": 1,
                                "_source": {
                                  "includes": [
                                    "locations.city.id",
                                    "locations.city.names"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I am trying to simplify dificult query to Elasticsearch

According the Elasticsearch documentation

To limit the documents on which all aggregations in a search run, use
a top-level query. This is faster than a single filter aggregation
with sub-aggregations.

So your simplified query is as following
GET /locations/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "locations",
                        "query": {
                            "terms": {
                                "locations.country.id": [
                                    "4"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "category.id": [
                            "24"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "city": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "locations"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_city_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "locations.city.id",
                        "size": 1000
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sources": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "size": 1,
                                "_source": {
                                    "includes": [
                                        "locations.city.id",
                                        "locations.city.names"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I don’t know your mapping. So this query could require correction
